# How i can extend more than one class in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, class, extend, inheritance

```
 <?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

    use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Webkul\Mpquotesystem\Helper\Data;
    use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

    class Index extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\AbstractAccount
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
         */
```

I want to extend my module controller here

how i can extend two classes

else any ideas???

Comment: no it's confusing in this question

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your requirement. Refer link

[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Comment: sure but  i have doubts

Comment: Magento are using php and php will not support multiple extend functionality. You have to use inheritance to achieve the same.

Comment: which inheritance

Comment: can i convert to interface

Comment: Depends on your requirement. Refer link http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Comment: Yes you can convert it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89914/discussion-between-prabhakaran7-and-mayur-jotaniya).

Comment: Interfaces may not include member variables in /var/www/html/equpo/app/code/Webkul/UiGrid/Controller/Mui/Index.php on li

Comment: Interfaces may not include member variables in /var/www/html/equpo/app/code/Webkul/UiGrid/Controller/Mui/Index.php on line 11

Comment: Extend functionality only work with public things.

Comment: i changed but interface extending one class

Comment: so that is showing problem..

Comment: i can  use 
this keyword to extend class 
**use**